# Hair Particle Displays Inside Object Instead of Outside?

Tags: modeling, particles, edit-mode

So I created this vertex group and the hair displays on the inside of my object.

[image]

How do I reverse the hairs to only display on the outside?

Comment: maybe flip the normals? select all in Edit mode and Alt N > Flip

Comment: ah okay that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip the normals: Select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Flip*.